# Login and redirect with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to redirect to a different page when email and password are right. with my script  i'm able to either the user has entered the right or wrong email and password. when its right it tells "correct email" and when it's wrong it tells "wrong email or password" in the "message" div.

Now what i want to do is when the message is "correct email" the user should be redirected to for example "inside.php". what script do i add to make it work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
   $('#message').html(msg);


        });
    });
});
```

Comment: just use window.location.href = inside.php in the success callback

Comment: on success , use window.location.href = desired_url

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {

    window.location.href = 'desired_url' ;


        });
    });
});
```

on success , use window.location.href = 'desired_url';

Comment: so where do i put the arguement if right or wrong? cos the redirect should only be down when the message is correct email

Comment: your_url?msg=success or whatever you want